# Extended complex plane and projection

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal L \subset \Bbb C$ (extended) a linea. Compute $\Pi(\mathcal L)$ which is the stereographic proyectionof the complex extended plane to the 2-sphere.

I do not know where to start, any help would be amazing.

Comment: A circle through the "point at infinity "?

Answer (score 1):

A circle through the "point at infinity".

Read about it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).